# How to get memory address from shm_open?

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap

I want to share memory using a file descriptor with another process created via `fork`.
The problem is that I get different address regions from `mmap`.
I want that `mmap` returns the same address value. Only in such case I can be sure that I really share the memory.

Probably it is possible to use `MAP_FIXED` flag to `mmap`, but how to get memory address from `shm_open`?

Is it possible to share memory via `shm_open` at all?

Maybe `shmget` must be used instead?

This is the minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(void)
{
  /* Create a new memory object */
  int fd = shm_open( "/dummy", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777 );
  if(fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Open failed:%m\n");
    return 1;
  }

  /* Set the memory object's size */
  size_t size = 4096; /* minimal */

  if (ftruncate(fd, size) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ftruncate: %m\n");
    return 1;
  }

  void *ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) return 1;

  void *ptr2 = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (ptr2 == MAP_FAILED) return 1;

  printf("%p\n%p\n", ptr, ptr2);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc test.c -lrt`.

This is the output:

```
0x7f3247a78000
0x7f3247a70000
```

**EDIT**

If I try to use method described in comment, child does not see changes in memory made by parent. Why? This is how I do it:

In parent:

```
shm_data = mmap(NULL, shm_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
...
snprintf(shared_memory, 20, "%p", shm_data);
execl("/path/to/prog", "prog", shared_memory, (char *) NULL);
```

In child:

```
...
void *base_addr;
sscanf(argv[1], "%p", (void **)&base_addr);
shm_data = mmap(base_addr, shm_size, PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
...
```

**EDIT2**

See also this question: [How to get memory address from memfd_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49567475/1487773)

Comment: If you want the virtual addresses to be the same, then you have to also share the virtual address itself using any of the possible IPC mechanisms. For example, the process can write the virtual address to another shared memory region and the other process can use `MAP_FIXED` with that virtual address.

Comment: I think the best way is not to use `shm_open` at all; instead, simply use `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` in parent, write the obtained address to in-memory file, pass its descriptor to child, and in child use `MAP_FIXED` with address read from the file descriptor, inherited from parent, as you advised.

Comment: Another option for passing address to child is in argument list to `execl`.

Comment: @HadiBrais see **EDIT**

Comment: Simply using the same virtual address with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` does not make the region shared. You have to use `shm_open`. Passing the virtual address as an argument to `execl` is fine.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194235/is-there-a-way-to-an-share-address-mapping-between-two-unrelated-processes-on-li?noredirect=1#comment127751665_72194235